# 64bit ubuntu 12.04 python cannot run an existing python file

Tags: python

absolute path, fails:

```
nan@UXN:~$ python /home/nan/google_appengine/goagent/local/proxy.py
python: can't open file '/home/nan/google_appengine/goagent/local/proxy.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

relative path, also fails:

```
nan@UXN:~$ cd /home/nan/google_appengine/goagent/local
nan@UXN:~/google_appengine/goagent/local$ python proxy.py
python: can't open file 'proxy.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have read some solutions, they say its a shared problem. and I ran：

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 lib32z1 lib32stdc++6 ia32-libs
```

but still fails. What should I do? thanks.

```
nan@UXN:~$ ls -alhs /home/nan/google_appengine/goagent/local/
total 6.3M
4.0K drwx------ 3 nan nan 4.0K Dec 15 10:59 .
4.0K drwx------ 4 nan nan 4.0K Dec 15 10:59 ..
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 2.7K Dec 12 23:58 addto-startup.js
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 3.3K Dec 12 23:58 addto-startup.py
248K -rw------- 1 nan nan 245K Dec 12 23:58 cacert.pem
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 2.9K Dec 12 23:58 CA.crt
4.0K drwx------ 2 nan nan 4.0K Dec 16 19:37 certs
 24K -rw------- 1 nan nan  24K Dec 12 23:58 goagent.exe
 16K -rw------- 1 nan nan  13K Dec 12 23:58 goagent-gtk.py
8.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 6.9K Dec 12 23:58 goagent-osx.command
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan  411 Dec 12 23:58 Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
644K -rw------- 1 nan nan 641K Dec 12 23:58 msvcr90.dll
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan   62 Dec 12 23:58 proxy.bat
8.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 4.4K Dec 15 11:07 proxy.ini
416K -rw------- 1 nan nan 413K Dec 23 11:17 proxy.pac
132K -rwx--x--x 1 nan nan 132K Dec 12 23:58 proxy.py
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 1.6K Dec 12 23:58 proxy.sh
2.4M -rw------- 1 nan nan 2.4M Dec 12 23:58 python27.dll
 44K -rw------- 1 nan nan  43K Dec 12 23:58 python27.exe
2.2M -rw------- 1 nan nan 2.2M Dec 12 23:58 python27.zip
8.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan 5.8K Dec 12 23:58 SwitchyOptions.bak
184K -rw------- 1 nan nan 182K Dec 12 23:58 SwitchySharp.crx
4.0K -rw------- 1 nan nan  134 Dec 12 23:58 uvent.bat
```

Comment: Can you run `ls -alhs /home/nan/google_appengine/goagent/local/` and add its output to your question?

Comment: @don.joey I try prefix 'sudo' and solve this problem. I still paste the infomation you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly traditional permissions problem.

You should make your file executable before you try and run it. Just do `chmod +x /home/nan/google_appengine/goagent/local/proxy.py`. That gives this file the permission to be executable (x).

Do not run these local script using `sudo` if you ask me. Unless you are 100% sure they can do nothing bad to your system.

## Correction

Hmm. I just read through your question again and your proxy.py already has executable permissions... So this cannot be the problem. Apologies. All suggestions welcome.