# deny access to Python as normal user

Tags: permissions, python, remote-access

im seeking for some scripts that deny access to the app python in my PC. example: a new user with low privileges can call python without type sudo or su, i wanna prevent this kind of situation by the same way that hosted users could start python without restrictions.

Comment: For general purpose use, there is no need to deny non-admin users access to Python. Python scripts are not a security hole. If a user lacking admin permission to use `sudo` calls a Python script that requires admin permission, the script will fail with a `permission denied` error. If you discover a way for non-admin users to abuse Python to gain admin access, please file a bug report and subscribe the Ubuntu Security Team to that bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for a [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) - the setup of which has been described in depth within [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165359/1601092). This allows only executables that can be found on the PATH (where you could exclude the `python` binary from for that specific user).